# Why in open balls is radius $r>0$?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

the usual definition is the following:

**Def.1**: *given $(a,f)$ a metric space, $c \in a$ and $r \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$, the open ball of radius $r$ about $c$ is the set $$\mathcal{B}_f(c,r)=\{x \in a| f((c,x))<r\}$$*

Why in open balls is radius $r>0$? And if in **Def.1** I have $r \in \Bbb{R}$ then $$\mathcal{B}_f(c,r)=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow r \leq 0$$ ???

Comment: Because a distance (in your case, $f$) is defined to be positive.

Comment: Note that iff $x\in \mathcal{B}$ then $0 \leq f(c,x) < r$ but if $r\leq 0$ then we have $0 \leq f(c,x) < r\leq 0$ wich cannot be. Therefore there is no $x\in\mathcal{B}$ so $\mathcal{B}$ must be empty.

Comment: Ok, I'll write it =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a metric space, a distance (in your case $f$) is defined to be non-negative, i.e. $\forall x,y\ f(x,y) \geq 0$

So let $x \in \mathcal{B}(c,r)$ then $f(c,x) < r$ but if $r \leq 0$ then $0\leq f(c,x) < r \leq 0$ wich cannot be. Therefore $\nexists x \in \mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B} = \emptyset$

For other implication ($\mathcal{B}_f(c,r) = \emptyset \Rightarrow r \leq 0$) just note that $f(c,c) = 0$ so if $c \notin \mathcal{B}$ then $r \leq 0$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(⋅,⋅)$ is the metric/distance which endows your metric space $A$ with a metric space structure, then $f(c,x)\geq 0$ for all $c,x\in A$ by definition of metric. This implies that the inequality $f(c,x)<r$, for $r<0$ has no solution.

Comment: therefore $r>0$ beacuse if $r\leq 0 $ then $\mathcal{B}_f(c,r)=\emptyset$, is it correct?

Comment: @mle if $r=0$ then only $c$ is in the ball

Comment: $r=0$ iff $f(c,x)=0\Leftrightarrow c=x$, i.e. the single point $c$ "is" the ball: @Belgi is right. For $r<0$ the ball is empty, so you are right.

Comment: mmmm @Avitus, if $f((c,x))=0$ and $r=0$ then $f((c,x)))=0<r=0 \to 0<0$ therefore $c \notin \mathcal{B}_f(c,r)$, is it correct?!

Comment: Ah ok, I am sorry: I meant $f(c,x)=r$ in my comment, i.e. I was looking at the boundary of the ball. If we want to solve $f(c,x)<r$ with $r=0$, i.e. $f(c,x)<0$ then we get no solution and the ball is the empty set. Did I understand correctly your remark?

Comment: @Avitus, yes ;)